# Unable to see any JupyterLab extensions

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

When using JupyterLab, no extensions are shown in the Discover section of the Extension Manager tab and none appear when I search for anything.

[image]

I have the Extension Manager enabled in the Commands tab and have node.js installed as the documentation says. Any ideas why this is happening?

I'm on JupyterLab v1.2.6

Answer (score 0):

Simply closing and reopening the Discover menu prompted the extensions to appear. May have been a coincidence and they needed time to load in (though this was several hours later) or maybe it needed refreshing, not sure.